# Ceiling fan wiring question

Tags: electrical, wiring, ceiling-fan, replacement

I am trying to install a ceiling fan where a light fixture was. When I took out the light fixture I noticed that there are 3 black wires all bundled together, (*and not being used*) 3 white wires with bundled together that were attached, one red wire that was attached, and then a copper wire.

My switch is a single dimmer switch.

My ceiling fan has 1 black, 1 white, 1 blue, 1 green.

Do I just attach black wire to the black bundle in the ceiling? and then white to white, blue to red, and green to copper - confused because the black wires weren't being used for the light itself.

Comment: Please upload the picture you took before disconnecting the light fixture.

Comment: Can you post the picture you took? Also, how do you want to be able to control the ceiling fan?

Comment: What do you mean "not being used"? You mean not *by the fan?*

Comment: Does your fan have a light? Some fans with a light kit will have 1 wire for the light and 1 for the fan so they can be controlled separately from a wall switch so you may need both the black and blue tied to the switched hot.

Comment: "*white wires with bundled together that were attached, one red wire that was attached, and then a copper wire.*" I can not wrap my head around that.  "*confused because the black wires weren't being used for the light itself.*"  What was being use to supply power to the previous light?